# import winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter;

Tags: java, android, twitter

i am doing an exercise from Orielly book, and they used that Twitter package that my api doesnt have.. where do i get that package from to set it inside my project?

Comment: can i have whole package hierarchy of that class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jtwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php)

(BTW - first link if you ask google about jtwitter...)

---

easiest way to use it in an eclipse project:

1. create a folder inside the project, like `lib`
2. copy the jar file(s) to that folder
3. right-click on the jar file in that folder and do a "add to build path"

All three steps have to be done on the package explorer.

Comment: How do i put it into eclipse?